# Failed none and iptables

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04

The problem is that when I ssh to my host with putty and enter user name, after that the password prompt delays. Found this is directly related to my iptables and can solve by changing default policy to ACCEPT. 
If default INPUT policy is ACCEPT, then password prompt is coming immediately.

```
Mar 13 00:05:01 server-ubuntu sshd[6154]: Connection from 192.168.0.10 port 26304
Mar 13 00:05:06 server-ubuntu sshd[6154]: Failed none for acid from 192.168.0.10 port 26304 ssh2
```

However, if default INPUT policy is DROP, I got slight delay in getting password prompt after I enter username

```
Mar 13 00:07:12 server-ubuntu sshd[6177]: Connection from 192.168.0.10 port 26333
Mar 13 00:07:35 server-ubuntu sshd[6177]: Failed none for acid from 192.168.0.10 port 26333 ssh2
```

For the second case, I tried to set default policy for FORWARD and OUTPUT chains to ACCEPT, but it didn't help. The only rule in this case is:

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source 00:26:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
```

00:26:XX:XX:XX:XX is the mac address from which I am trying to ssh to server's LAN(eth1).

I'm sure there has to be some rule, which I can use while default INPUT chain policy is DENY in order to get password prompt immediately. I realize that the error message in the log is something normal and part of some verification procedure.

Comment: Looks like if I set `UseDNS no` in sshd config then the problem is solved. But this means that the server itself is failing to send/receive DNS queries. How to enable it from iptables?

Comment: I, too, suspect DNS.  Can you post the output of `iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` so we can suggest a rule to permit DNS?

Comment: Well, actually just added `-A INPUT -i eth0 -p UDP --sport 53 -j ACCEPT` and solved the issue! Thx

Comment: Well done, you!  Seriously, although breaking DNS can break lots of stuff, it can take a **long** time to work out what's going on.  I think you should give yourself a pat on the back for some quality debugging, post that answer, and accept it - since it's right!

Comment: Adding `-A INPUT -i eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` will allow return packages for outbound connections.

Comment: Good point, Mark.  You can combine the two, too, so `-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` can be used to permit only DNS packets which are responses to recent queries, if you're feeling extra security-minded.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above.

The pause was caused by iptables blocking DNS queries. It was solved by opening port 53

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p UDP --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```